# How can I store the biggest value of a set of many values in a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, max

Im using an array that lets the user choose a certain amount of of variables, and each one of these variables will become a random number. However, how can I take the biggest of those random numbers and store it in a variable? Im fairly new at Java, so a simple, understandable way to do this would be perfect. Thanks in advance!

```
int [] arr; 
Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in); 
n = reader.nextInt(); 
array = new int [n]; 
for (n = 0; n < array.length; n++ ) 
{ 
x = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1; 
System.out.println(x); 
System.out.println("Biggest Value is: " + );
```

}

Comment: show us your code pls

Comment: ok, here it is (minus the essentials)
            int [] arr;
        Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
       
        n = reader.nextInt();                               array = new int [n];
            for (n = 0; n < array.length; n++ )
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println("Biggest Value is: " + );
            }
This way it asks the user how many numbers do they want, then it creates a random between 10 and 1

Comment: Edit your question and paste it and format it. @luckyredgrave

Answer (score 0):

You may use an integer variable to keep track of the highest number. While iterating if you come across a number greater than highest variable, make that number as highest and continue iterating till the end of the loop.

```
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (n = 0; n < array.length; n++ ){
    x = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    if(x > highest){
        highest = x;
    }
}

System.out.println("Highest number is " + highest);
```

Comment: while that may answer the question an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Coul you please explain it though? What is that Integer.MIN_VALUE part? what does it do?

Comment: Integer.MIN_VALUE is a integer constant holding the minimum value an int can have i.e -2^31 . Why are we doing this? Because lets say if we assign int highest= 0 instead of Integer.MIN_VALUE and your array contains {-1,-4,-21} then the highest number printed will be 0 instead of -1.